# Submit a form without validitating required fields primefaces

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to have a form with JSF (Primefaces) to have a required field (the username is this example) to be required when saved. Also you can add books to every user, a user can have 0 ... n books. If you add a new book, it is required to give it an author and a name.

I tried it with the code below and already tried many ways of the [Partial Processing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf) of Primefaces. However, it is not working correctly. Sometimes I have to enter the required username to add a book or save it not working at all. Is there a way, to only check the required username on save and ignore the required author and bookname?

This is the code for the example:

```
        <h:form>
            <p:outputPanel id=„userdetails“>
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{bean.name}" />
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:inputText id="txt_title" value="#{createBookBean.book.title}"
                required="true" />
            <p:inputText id="txt_author" required="true"
                value="#{createBookBean.book.author}" />

            <p:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" />
            <p:commandButton id="btn_add" value="Add"
                update="books msgs @parent" action="#{createBookBean.reinit}">
                <p:collector value="#{createBookBean.book}"
                    addTo="#{createBookBean.books}" />
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:outputPanel id="books">
                <p:dataTable id="booksTable" value="#{createBookBean.books}"
                    var="book">
                    <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" />

                    <h:outputText value="#{book.author}" />

                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandLink value="Remove" update=":form:books"
                            process=":form:books">
                            <p:collector value="#{book}"
                                removeFrom="#{createBookBean.books}" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:outputPanel>

            <p:commandButton value="Save" update="msgs" process="@form"
                action="#{bean.save()}"></p:commandButton>  // button to save, and ignore required bookname
        </h:form>
```

// button to save, and ignore required bookname

Comment: Try `immediate` attribute of commandButton

Comment: Please post valid XML code. Please do not use something like MS Office Word as XML editor. Your XML code is polluted with curly quotes which would impossibly have successfully compiled and executed by JSF/Facelets. Also please cutdown the code to the minimum necessary code in order to reproduce the exact problem by just copy'n'paste'n'running. For example, those output labels and column headers are certainly not necessary in order to reproduce the problem. This keeps your code short and the cause can quicker be spotted by experts. Try to get rid of that scrollbar next to the code snippet.

Comment: I hope its better now. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

For that purpose you can use `immediate` attribute of `commandButton`:

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" update="msgs" process="@form"
    action="#{bean.save()}" immediate="true" />
```